# Will Socket programming in java work over internet?

Tags: java

I'm trying to send files from one computer to another using Java Sockets. It works successfully on local LAN, But its not working over internet.Could anyone please tell me what is the problem and how i should solve it???
thanks.

Comment: You need to show us a bit of code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine, provided the devices *en route* allow it. Can you access the port on the remote machine ? Try using

```
$ telnet remotehost remoteport
```

and see if that connects. You may also want to check the route via [traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) or [tracert](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tracert.mspx?mfr=true)